# How to handle global JS variable in an instanceable Liferay Portlet?

Tags: javascript, liferay, liferay-6

A portlet in Liferay can be added either once per page or multiple times per page, when the portlet can be added multiple times it is also called as an instanceable Portlet.

In such an instanceable Portlet, I need global JS variables in the scope of one portlet. Currently I have the JS code in my jsp file (ugly, I know ^^) and use the portlet namespace in my variable names, e.g.:

```
var <portlet:namespace/>oldUsedCPUsValue = 0;
```

But now I want to put all my JS code into the `main.js` file, where I obviously cannot use the portlet namespace. How could I do this? A global array and as key the portlet namespace?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is not my specialty, but I'd put just code into main.js (you can namespace that yourself and don't care if it gets overloaded with the same code from another portlet (There's my javascript-special-knowledge: I didn't even check if main.js will be included twice - if you check it it might even just be included once.

Then call/initialize it from the jsp page where you can either use namespacing (if you have requirements for them to be completely global.

Another way to go (if you don't care for the actual namespace and just need one namespace) is the use of AlloyUI (an extension to YUI), namespacing comes for free with these:

```
AUI().use('node', 'module2', 'foo', function (A) {
  // your code and 'global' variables go here.

  A.foo.bar();

  // the namespace ends here
});
```